# How do you obtain permissions from web-nfc API?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, nfc, webnfc

I'm trying to get Web NFC to work through the [Web NFC API](https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/), but I can't get it past an error message of `NotAllowedError: NFC permission request denied.`

I'm using this on Chrome 89 Dev on a Windows 10 computer, and the source code is being run locally.

I have tried the examples posted on the Internet also, including the [Google sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/) but it returns the same error. I'm not concerned with it being experimental at this point as referring to [this](https://wpt.fyi/results/web-nfc?label=experimental&label=master&aligned) does show it has successfully passed the necessary tests, including permissions.

The HTML/JS code I'm using is below, and I've read the [specification point 9.3](https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/#obtaining-permission), but I can't make sense of it to write it as code, so is there a guideline algorithm that would be helpful here to resolve this?

```js
async function readTag() {
  if ("NDEFReader" in window) {
    const reader = new NDEFReader();
    try {
      await reader.scan();
      reader.onreading = event => {
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        for (const record of event.message.records) {
          consoleLog("Record type:  " + record.recordType);
          consoleLog("MIME type:    " + record.mediaType);
          consoleLog("=== data ===\n" + decoder.decode(record.data));
        }
      }
    } catch(error) {
      consoleLog(error);
    }
  } else {
    consoleLog("Web NFC is not supported.");
  }
}

async function writeTag() {
  if ("NDEFWriter" in window) {
    const writer = new NDEFWriter();
    try {
      await writer.write("helloworld");
      consoleLog("NDEF message written!");
    } catch(error) {
      consoleLog(error);
    }
  } else {
    consoleLog("Web NFC is not supported.");
  }
}

function consoleLog(data) {
  var logElement = document.getElementById('log');
  logElement.innerHTML += data + '\n';
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="webnfc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <button onclick="readTag()">Test NFC Read</button>
  <button onclick="writeTag()">Test NFC Write</button>
</p>
<pre id="log"></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://web.dev/nfc/#security-and-permissions

> Web NFC is only available to top-level frames and secure browsing contexts (HTTPS only). Origins must first request the "nfc" permission while handling a user gesture (e.g a button click). The NDEFReader scan() and write() methods trigger a user prompt, if access was not previously granted.

I guess you are running from a `file://` URL as you said "locally" which is not supported.
You need to host it from a local web server using a `https://` URL

Once in the right scope trying to scan or write should trigger a user prompt.

You can also check permissions see https://web.dev/nfc/#check-for-permission

**Update:**
So I tried the sample page https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/

And this works for me on Android Chrome 87 with "Experimental Web Platform features" enabled

When you hit the scan button A dialog asking for permission pops up.

Comparing the code in this sample to yours I notice that does:-

```
ndef.addEventListener("reading" , ({ message, serialNumber }) => { ...
```

Where as yours does:-

```
ndef.onreading = event => { ...
```

I don't know if it is the style setting what happens on the Event or something else (Hey this is all experimental)

**Update2**
To answer the question from the comments of Desktop support.

So you should be some of the desktop/browser combinations at the moment and may be in the future there will be wider support as this is no longer experimental standards. Obviously as your test link suggest Chrome on a Linux Desktop should work as this is really similar to Android Support, with all the NFC device handling done by `libnfc` and the browser just has to know about this library instead of every type usb or other device than can do NFC.

From what seen of NFC support on Windows, most of this is focussed on direct controlling the NFC reader via USB as just another USB device, while there is a libnfc equivalent in `Windows.Networking.Proximity` API's I've not come across any NFC reader saying they support this or anybody using it.

For Mac Deskstop, given that Apple are behind the curve with NFC support in iOS, I feel their desktop support will be even further behind even though it could be similar to Linux.

Comment: Ok, so I've integrated the permissions code and hosted it onto https://tina.rf.gd (Inspect the page for the source codes) and now I'm not sure what's going on as I can't even get it to display anything in the console nor a user prompt.

Comment: Updated the answer as I was able to get some other sample code to work.

Comment: Messed around with the code and I finally got it to work with your code change; thank you! Do you think these results could be repeated on a desktop browser? I have seen many successes for desktop Chrome support (e.g. https://wpt.fyi/results/web-nfc?label=experimental&label=master&aligned) but I'm uncertain why it's not handling it the same way, even with a connected NFC reader ://

Comment: Added Update about desktop support, as the link to the test results show support on Chrome on Linux should be as good as on Android (Because the the hood they are really the same thing)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for sharing your insight -- it's really appreciated :)

Comment: hey @andrew I was just reading back your updated answer about libnfc working on Linux; it seemed like you have rough ideas on how there might be a chance to link libnfc within the browser? I have it working standalone from the terminal, and I'm trying to figure out how I can incorporate it into a web application, so do you have any tips on that?

Comment: Sorry no tips, this was just a general observation of how nfc was handled at the low level on various OS's and possibly how difficult it would be for various Browser developers to add support for this standard. I have no inside knowledge of various web browser plans or timelines to add support in various OS's

Comment: Aha, worth a try! Thanks anyways for all your help @andrew :)

Answer (score 2):

As you can read at https://web.dev/nfc/#browser-support, Web NFC only supports Android for now which is why you get `"NotAllowedError: NFC permission request denied."` error on Windows.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!-- is there any trials ongoing for Windows support and the API?

Comment: There's none at the moment.